# Google Drive API, get total files added for the entire organization

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I got a request to pull a count of all files added to google drive for our organization.
Basically count files for each user in their google drive.  The API has a list method that I could call a count on, but I would have to iterate through each userId and get the count.  That would take forever (120,353 records). What am I missing here as this seems possible...
I noticed in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/standard_fields) they mention Standard Fields and Custom methods, one standard is called **total_size**  (int32  The total count of items in the list irrespective of pagination.) *I just have not figured out in .net how to use that yet.*

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with the batch route and where I could I used threaded operations to spin out multiple request.  Plus coded to ensure none of them exceeded the request per minute threshold google has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Sorry, there is no global endpoint for that

I think you are looking for a simple endpoint that returns the total number of files in a domain, but unfortunately there are none as it is not how Google Drive stores information.

#### One possible approach

Using a service account with domain wide delegation. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

- Impersonate an admin account and get a list of all the users [Ref](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list)
- With that information, impersonate each user and make Drive API request for each user. You will likely need to make a few requests for each, as the page size is limited. Use page tokens. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- Store a list of all the ID's.
- Count Unique ID's.

*Remember to set permissions in both the GCP console and the Admin console for the service account.*
Not exactly a simple solution and depending on experience, may take some time to implement, the hardest part possibly being getting service accounts set up, but it sounds like you are already there.

#### Ways to optimize

- Use the `q` parameter with an argument of `q='"me" in owners'`. This will significantly cut the number of files you get because each file by definition only has one owner.
- Since you only need the IDs for both the users and files, be sure to only ask for the ID's in the `fields` parameter of all the requests, this will speed things up considerably.
- You can also take advantage of [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance) to make up to 100 calls at the same time. So if you had 100 users, you could make 100 requests in one go!

---

This may not be ideal for you if you need to get constant updates of this number, but if you only need periodical updates (every week, possibly every day), then it should be fine.

#### Performance

For arguments sake, say you have 120,000 files. If you implement the simplest solution without the `q` parameter, duplicate files will come up because they are shared and so will appear on more than one persons Drive. Lets just multiply it by 10 to be safe, so 1.2 million files to get the ID for. Again, lets say you implemented the least optimized solution and requested the maximum 1000 files per request, and you made the requests in series. Considering the average time for a general request is around 2 seconds, lets round that up to 5 seconds. So in a potential bad case:

```
1200000 / 1000 = 1200 requests
1200 * 5 = 6000 seconds
6000 / 60 = 100 minutes
```

Of course if you used batching and you had 10 users that might be cut by a factor of 10, and so might only take 10 minutes if all users had the same number of files.

If you use the `q` parameter then it again, you are cutting out a factor of 10 so it would take 10 minutes. If you had the perfect batching situation then it could take 1 minute!

#### Maintenance of the total number.

You could additionally use the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started) to query if files are created and deleted, and so, maintain the total number of files in your domain by incrementing it on every created file and decrementing on every delete.

---

#### References

- [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started)
- [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)
- [Admin API - users List request](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list)
- [Drive API - files List request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Drive Batch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anyway to use the google drive api and be authenticated as an organization.

However, you will still have to do a lot of iterating so I wouldn't be too worried about iterating over users. The google drive api returns a set number of files per page meaning numerous api calls as you iterate over the pages.

I think the bigger computational hazard is counting shared files over and over (that user's may or may not have added to their MyDrive folder).